# Signing application with Jenkins

Tags: android, ant, utf-8, character-encoding, jenkins

Usually I sign my application through Eclipse, with the Android Tools -> Export Signed Application.

Now, I want to use Jenkins to automatically build and sign my application.
Therefore I have installed Jenkins on a Mac Mini and created a file `ant.properties` with my keystore credentials. But signing my application with Jenkins fails:

```
BUILD FAILED
The following error occurred while executing this line:
Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect: Password verification failed
```

Currently I have 2 issues which could be causing the signing to fail:

**1) My Alias contains a space**

But since I use "" (quotes) I don't think this should be the problem.

**2) My Keystorepass contains a non-utf8 character**

Here's my `ant.properties` files, used for signing with Jenkins
`ant.properties`:

```
key.store=mykey.store
key.alias="My Alias"
key.store.password=*€*
key.alias.password=***
```

As you can see, I have a non-utf8 character which I think is causing the signing process to fail. When using Eclipse, I can just copy and paste my password and everything works as expected. But with Jenkins it fails everytime.

**Tried so far:**

I tried to manually sign my application through the command line (on windows 7) and jarsigner by using this line (note, the € sign is replaced by a ? on my windows 7 cmd line, when i paste the password):

```
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore mykey.store MyApp.apk "My Alias" -storepass *?* -keypass ***
```

And this works.

However, my Jenkins installation runs on a mac mini, where the same command asks me to input my keystore pass. When I enter my pass, or copy/paste it, it gives me the following error:

```
RuntimeException: keystore load: keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect
```

**Strange**

Due to the password having a non-utf8 character, it appears different on each platform when I copy and paste it. E.g. currently I have seen the following characters:

```
WINDOWS TXT FILE (ORIGINAL): *€*
WINDOWS PASTE IN CMD: *?*
MACMINI OPEN ORIGINAL FILE: *Ä*
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A .properties file needs to be ISO-8859-1 encoded, so it's worth double-checking you have no UTF-8 (or otherwise) encoded characters in the file, and making sure the correct escape codes are used.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.properties):

> The encoding of a `.properties` file is ISO-8859-1, also known as Latin-1. All non-Latin-1 characters must be entered by using Unicode escape characters, e.g. `\uHHHH` where `HHHH` is a hexadecimal index of the character in the Unicode character set.

Comment: Thnx for the tip. Finally I downloaded KeyStore explorer, which I used to change my password.